# JSch Session Connecting

Tags: java, gwt, jdbc, ssh, jsch

Hi I am trying to connect via ssh tunneling to a database on a server, but I can't even get the Jsch session to connect. I am attempting to do this in GWT as part of my back-end code. So this is in the Implementation part of the server side code. 
I am not that familiar with servers in general. Typically in terminal I type:

> ssh -x username@xxxxx.xxx.edu

Then I am prompted for my password and I enter the password and then I am in.

So in java my code is as follows:

```
String host="xxxxx.xxx.edu";

String user="username";
String password="password";

Session session= null;
try{
            //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
}
```

I've double checked the username and the password and the host string and they are all what I use in terminal successfully.

The error I get on the 'session.connect()' line is as follows: (scroll right to see whole error)

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission xxxxx.xxx.edu resolve)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:341)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:194)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
at com.front.server.GameServiceImpl.createGame(GameServiceImpl.java:39)
```

Is there something I am missing? Is this not identical to what I do in terminal to sign in via ssh? I have also tried prepending 'ssh://' to the host string as well but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that there is no problem with the code above. I copied/pasted it into a simple java main and it worked fine. It appears there is something wrong with putting that same code in GWT back-end.

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception message, it seems that the problem has not come from JSch.

Refer to [Security and Permissions](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html) on java.sun.com:

> All applets and any applications invoked with a security manager must
>   be granted explicit permission to access local system resources apart
>   from read access to the directory and its subdirectories where the
>   program is invoked. The Java platform provides permissions to allow
>   various levels of access to different types of local information.

,and see [SocketPermission](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#SocketPermission) section.